# Python geopandas - editing geodata

Tags: python, geospatial, edit, geopandas

I tried to edit geographic coordinates in shape file using .loc to the proper cell, but everytime I was getting the same error: `TypeError: Value should be either a BaseGeometry or None`

I even tried to paste into the cell totally the same geographic coordinates, but still had the same error. Where is the problem here?

```
import geopandas as gpd
fp = 'http://gis-lab.info/data/mos-adm/mo.geojson'
map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)
map_df.loc[[145],['geometry']]= 'MULTIPOLYGON (((37.2905 55.80199, 37.29542 55.803, 37.29663 55.8032, 37.29777 55.80335, 37.29864 55.80345, 37.29969 55.80352, 37.30356 55.80356, 37.30327 55.80318, 37.30292 55.80248, 37.30278 55.80127, 37.30235 55.79863, 37.29822 55.79763, 37.29447 55.79672, 37.29441 55.79679, 37.29412 55.79671, 37.29417 55.79663, 37.29321 55.79641, 37.29326 55.79806, 37.2905 55.80199)))'
map_df.plot()
```

Comment: Can you show your code and your data?

Comment: @martinfleis, I have updated answer

Comment: @martinfleis, if there any possibility to input WKT with 2 or more multipolylons, coz when I try to do this I've got this error: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: Two MultiPolygons into a single cell? Not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: @martinfleis, I put this code and it had given me that error:
`string = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((37.2905 55.80199, 37.29542 55.803, 37.29663 55.8032, 37.29777 55.80335, 37.29864 55.80345, 37.29969 55.80352, 37.30356 55.80356, 37.30327 55.80318, 37.30292 55.80248, 37.30278 55.80127, 37.30235 55.79863, 37.29822 55.79763, 37.29447 55.79672, 37.29441 55.79679, 37.29412 55.79671)), ((37.36526 55.77173, 37.36539 55.77181, 37.37506 55.76732, 37.38186 55.76422, 37.39712 55.7568, 37.40709 55.752, 37.42212 55.74483)))'`
I think coz of 2 polygons here

Comment: That is know bug. I have edited my answer to include workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometry in geopandas in stored as `shapely.geometry` objects. You are trying to pass a string (WKT) representation instead, that is why it causes the above mentioned error. You have to first convert your string to shapely geometry.

```
from shapely.wkt import loads

string = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((37.2905 55.80199, 37.29542 55.803, 37.29663 55.8032, 37.29777 55.80335, 37.29864 55.80345, 37.29969 55.80352, 37.30356 55.80356, 37.30327 55.80318, 37.30292 55.80248, 37.30278 55.80127, 37.30235 55.79863, 37.29822 55.79763, 37.29447 55.79672, 37.29441 55.79679, 37.29412 55.79671, 37.29417 55.79663, 37.29321 55.79641, 37.29326 55.79806, 37.2905 55.80199)))'
geom = loads(string)
df.loc[145, 'geometry'] = geom
```

If you try to assign multi-part geometry, it may in some cases lead to `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable` which is know bug in pandas (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/992). The workaround would be passing it through GeoSeries.

```
geom = loads(string)
df.loc[145, 'geometry'] = geopandas.GeoSeries([geom]).values
```

Comment: I try passing it through a GeoSeries, but I still get that error when trying to assign a MultiPolygon.  Any other workaround?

Comment: The validation rules are really strict in gdfpandas and fiona is impossible to install on windows, this was helpful though